# contact listener issues

Tags: c++, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I don't know much C++ and I am trying to implement a solution I found - ([Getting the world's contactListener in Box2D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866715/getting-the-worlds-contactlistener-in-box2d?lq=1)) using Cocos2d-box2d. Here is the Contact Listener.

SubcContactListener.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "Box2D.h"
#import <vector>
typedef std::pair<b2Fixture*, b2Fixture*> fixturePair;
typedef std::vector<fixturePair> thingsThatTouched;


extern thingsThatTouched g_touchingFixtures;

class SubcContactListener : public b2ContactListener    {

public:

    void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact);
void EndContact(b2Contact* contact);
};
```

SubcContactListener.mm:

```
#import "SubcContactListener.h"

void SubcContactListener:: BeginContact(b2Contact *contact) {

    thingsThatTouched->push_back( make_pair(contact->GetFixtureA(), contact->GetFixtureB()) );

}

void SubcContactListener:: EndContact(b2Contact *contact)   {

}
```

I get an

```
Expected unqualified-id
```

error at the line

```
thingsThatTouched.push_back( make_pair(contact->GetFixtureA(), contact->GetFixtureB()) );
```

in the BeginContact method of SubcContactListener.mm.
I also get an

```
Unexpected type name 'thingsThatTouched': expected expression
```

error at the lines

```
b2Fixture* fixtureA = thingsThatTouched[i].first;
b2Fixture* fixtureB = thingsThatTouched[i].second;
```

in the tick method of the HelloWorldLayer class.

***UPDATED:***

I am trying to create a weldjoint when two sprites (which have their own classes) collide. Here is what I did in the tick method of the HelloWorld.mm:

```
b2WeldJoint *weldJoint;
b2WeldJointDef weldJointDef;

    for (int i = 0; i < touchingBodies.size(); i++) {
    b2Body* bodyA = touchingBodies[i].first;
    b2Body* bodyB = touchingBodies[i].second;

    weldJointDef.Initialize(bodyA, bodyB, bodyA->GetWorldCenter());
    weldJointDef.collideConnected = false;
    weldJoint = (b2WeldJoint*)world->CreateJoint(&weldJointDef);

}
touchingBodies.clear();
```

But I get the following error:

```
Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error
"_touchingBodies", referenced from:
  SubcContactListener::BeginContact(b2Contact*) in SubcContactListener.o
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`thingsThatTouched` is a typedef. It is just synonymous to a type but not an identifier/variable. In other words its not an object by itself. I think you are supposed to use `g_touchingFixtures` where you are using `thingsThatTouched`.

When you say,

```
typedef int myOwnInt;
```

Now you can't use,

```
myOwnInt = 10;   // Wrong. myOwnInt is just a type like how int is.

myOwnInt i = 10;
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Ok. What is `_touchingBodies` which linker is complaining about ? If it is has `extern` linkage, are you compiling that file too along with the current source file ?

Comment: `extern thingsThatTouched touchingBodies;
`Yes I am compiling both together.

Comment: `touchingBodies` is in the `contactListerner.h` file.

Comment: Where is `g_touchingFixtures` defined ?

Comment: sorry for not mentioning. I replaced it with `touchingBodies` since I am want to create a `weldJoint`. I also changed the `typedef's `to take `b2Body`instead of `b2Fixture`